# Why my custom action is not called in a DoAction event?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have created my own CA to perform a specific task.
I don't understand why my CA seems to be ignored when called from a publish event...
Here is my code:

```
<Publish Event="DoAction" Value="myActionId" Order="1">1</Publish>
...
<Binary Id="myAction" SourceFile="..\bin\Debug\myCA.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="myActionId" BinaryKey="myAction" DllEntry="MySimpleAction" Return="check" />
```

When I put my CA in a InstallUISequence or InstallExecuteSequence, it works fine...
The log says:

> Action 10:33:07: myActionId. Action start 10:33:07: myActionId.
>   Action ended 10:33:09: myActionId. Return value 1.

Any idea? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file says that CA is called. However, it might not behave the way you expect it to, that's why you think it isn't. For instance, it is known that [MsiProcessMessage can't be called from DoAction event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368322.aspx). Verify whether it's the case with your CA.

Comment: That's it! I didn't knew about that... Thanks!